# radical of sum of two ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

$I$ and $J$ are ideals in $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.

Show that $\sqrt{I+J}=\sqrt{\sqrt{I}+\sqrt{J}}$.

I have no idea how to prove it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"$\subset$" is trivial. For the other inclusion, assume $x \in \sqrt{\sqrt{I} + \sqrt{J}}$.
Then there exists $m$ such that $x^m \in \sqrt{I} + \sqrt{J}$. Say $x^m = y + z$ with $y^n \in I$ and $z^k \in J$. What can you say about $(x^m)^{n + k - 1}$?

Comment: $(x^m)^{n+k-1}=(y+z)^{n+k-1}=c_0y^{n+k-1}z^0+\cdots+c_iy^{n+k-i-1}z^i+\cdots+c_{n+k-1}y^0z^{n+k-1}$. Terms that can be divided by $y^n$ are in $I$ and terms that can be divided by $z^k$ are in $J$. So $(x^m)^{n+k-1}$ can be written in form of $a+b$ where $a\in I,b\in J$.

Comment: Thank you, Serkan. Your proof is beautiful!

Comment: Essentially this proof reproves well-known standard facts instead of just using them (for example that the radical ideal is an ideal). When you replace element calculations by objects and their universal properties (i.e. their *modern definition*), the claim becomes much clearer and easier to prove. As always ...

Answer (score 12):

You don't have to argue with elements. $\sqrt{I+J}$ is the smallest radical ideal which contains $I+J$, i.e. which contains $I$ and $J$. On the other side, $\sqrt{\sqrt{I}+\sqrt{J}}$ is the smallest radical ideal which contains $\sqrt{I}+\sqrt{J}$, i.e. which contains $\sqrt{I}$ and $\sqrt{J}$, i.e. which contains $I$ and $J$. Thus both radical ideals are equal.

In general, for every closure operator $C$ on a partial order, we have $C(A \vee B) = C(C(A) \vee C(B))$ for all elements $A,B$. This is purely formal. In the example above, we have the partial order of ideals and $C(A)=\sqrt{A}$. You can also take the partial order of subsets of a topological space and $C(A)=\overline{A}$. But actually here the union of two closed sets is already closed, so that the right hand side simplifies. The corresponding statement for radical ideals does *not* hold and this has actually an algebro-geometric interpretation. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322872). Also note that even more generally $C(\vee_i A_i)=C(\vee_i C(A_i))$. In the case of subsets of a topological space the right hand side doesn't simplify.

Comment: Thank you for the concise proof and further explanation.