# Domain without any non trivial integral extensions (any monic polynomial $f \in A[x] \setminus \{1\}$ has a root in $A$) is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

> Let $A$ be an integral domain. Assume that any monic polynomial (different from $1$) with coefficients in $A$ has a root in $A$. Does it follow that $A$ is a field (necessarily algebraically closed)?

If we assume that *any* non constant polynomial $f \in A[X]$ has a root in $A$ (an "algebraically closed ring"), then $A$ is a field, for $aX-1$ has a root in $A$ for any $a \in A \setminus \{0\}$. But what happens if the assumption is only made on monic polynomials?

I think that my condition is equivalent to say that $A$ has no integral extension, except $A$ itself.

I didn't find any obvious counter-examples. I tried to show that any maximal ideal had to be $0$, without success.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [This comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322872/conditions-for-sqrt-mathfraka-b-sqrt-mathfraka-sqrt-mathfrak?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment701349_322922) is quite related. Such rings $A$ are called "absolutely integrally closed" (see e.g. [Definition 3.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.2220v4.pdf) or §1 [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870871800075)).

Comment: More general question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681357/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it might be the ring of integers of an algebraically closed field, for example (as Eric Wofsey notes in the comments, this idea can be generalized). The integral closure $B$ of $\Bbb Z$ in $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ satisfies this property. Any nonconstant polynomial $f\in B[x]$ necessarily has a root in $\overline{\Bbb Q}$. If we assume $f$ is monic, then because $B$ is integrally closed, the root of $f$ must lie in $B$.

Comment: More generally, you can replace $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ with any algebraically closed field $K$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ with any subring of $K$ that is not a field.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if actually all the examples must arise as integral closure of a subring $D$ of an algebraically closed field $K$ (such that $D$ is not a field)?

Comment: @Watson: Sure, rather trivially: just let $D=A$ and $K$ be an algebraically closed field containing $A$.  Your condition says that $D$ is already integrally closed in $K$.  (In fact, you can take $K$ to just be the field of fractions of $A$, since your condition implies the field of fractions is algebraically closed.)